# How to change a running process' stdin from keyboard to file on linux?

Tags: linux, process, stdin

I have a running process on linux platform

I want to change the the running process' stdin to a file.

then I can control the process by writing sth into the file.

Is it  possible without changing the process' source code.?

thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a question more suitable for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) as it does not seem to be a programming question which is [the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. When posting on either of those sites, you might want to provide a little more information about what process are we talking about and so on. As it stands, your question is such that it is impossible to produce an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change file descriptor of running process you can use gdb. Try this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/test_file

gdb -p PROCESS_PID
  p close(0) 
  p open("/tmp/test_file", 0400)

echo "TEST" >> /tmp/test_file
```

After echo close gdb debugger by pressing q.

Comment: this does't work. after echo the first text at gdb, such as "TEST", the runing process exits.